# pyspark set ttl on rows in Cassandra table

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm using PySpark to manipulate data in Cassandra and want to setup ttl on rows. I tried the following code it ran fine, but after the run i checked the table, the record/row was still there.

```
def set_ttl(tableName, keyspaceName, dataDf):
  (dataDf.write
          .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
          .options(table = tableName, keyspace = keyspaceName, ttl = str(1))
          .mode("append")
          .save())


emails='abc@test.com'.split(",")
df = read_table(my_table, my_keyspace,"*").where(col("email").isin(emails))

set_ttl(my_table, my_keyspace, df)
```

I googled around and got conflict answers, some said it's doable but other said it's supported. since I didn't get any error when I ran the script so I assume it should work? Please help.

Comment: If you want to add a notebook tag, add the appropriate one, e.g. [tag:spark-notebook], [tag:jupyter-notebook]

Comment: it's Databricks Notebook, and there is no such an option

Comment: Then either don't add the tag, or create a specific one for it, but certainly don't create a new one for all notebooks, as there are many types and that's very ambiguous.